# Parameters: Where are they declared?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a class that has a `private` member that is declared on the heap in the constructor. Then, in the destructor, it's `delete`ed. Now, I'd like to add a method to modify that variable. I'd like to be able to use a reference, but I'm not sure about the specifics of the memory involved, and I'd like to know I'm doing it correctly (the project could be fairly large in the memory department).

```
class A
{
private: std::string str;
/* ... */
public:
A() 
{
str = new std::string("");  
}
~A(){delete str;}

// method to modify str.
};
```

If I pass by reference, what steps should I take to eliminate memory leaks and minimize memory usage? That being said, I don't want to be all that aggresive with optimizations yet.

**How should I write my getters and setters for a member that is on the heap? Copy constructors, something else?**

Comment: Note that the class std::string already performs it's own memory management, which includes encapsulating the copy constructor, move constructor and assignment operator. It is not necessary for you, when aggregating a class that already has this, to do it again.

Comment: Therefore, if in your case the class that is aggregated (the private member) has its own memory management (as std::string does), rather don't allocate it on the heap. If you are concerned with regards to having to much dependencies in your header file, which may be a reason to use the heap, then rather use the pimpl_ idiom.

Comment: Don't use pointers and heap allocation until you absolutely need it.

Comment: Did you actually try compiling this?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths No--that was meant to be some hybrid between pseudo-code and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, `private: std::string str;` should be `private: std::string* str;`

your current memory management model is a [classic RIIA model.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30642&seqNum=8). First, there are several questions to be cleared.

- Will the `str` object solely owned by class `A`?
- do you want to use `str` out of the lifetime of class `A`?

If you answer no to the above, then this model doesn't suit your need very well.

Otherwise, you could continue to implement those member functions, here I just give some clues.

Getters can return a reference back,

```
 std::string const& getStr() {
    return *str;
 }
```

Setter could just change the value,

```
 void setStr(std::string const& s){
    *str = s;
 }
```

For the copy constructor, you could just call copy constructor from `std::string` and make a deep copy,

```
 A(A const& obj){
    str = new std::string(*obj.str);
 }
```

Comment: I think the wiki page of RAII is terrible - a much better link would be http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30642&seqNum=8

Comment: Rather than declaring `str` as a pointer, it would be better to do as the other answered suggests: not using `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

You are over complicating your problem. The code should look like:

```
class A
{
    private: std::string str;

    public:
        A() { str = ""; }
        std::string GetStr() { return str; }
        void SetStr(std::string value) { str = value; }
};
```

Constructor is initing your data member with empty string. You do not need any destructior. The string class will do all the cleanup for you. And you can use your data field like in the sample methods above.

Do not add any special copy/move methods. Just carefully read the manual on how to use the string class.

Comment: The default constructor for `std::string` already initializes it to the empty string.

Comment: Getter and setter should use const & for return and parameter respectively.  :-)